# Java field has wrong value after returned from a method, while calculating it with a void method produces correct result

Tags: java, methods, field, pass-by-reference

Here is the following piece of code I wrote to compute the equilibrium index of a given array.

```
public class Equilibrium{
    private int lowerSum =0;

     public int equilibrium(int[] A) {
        for(int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
        {
            if(lowerSum(A, i) == upperSum(A,i))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;

     }

    private int lowerSum(int[] ar, int index)
    {
        if(index == 0)
            return 0;
        lowerSum += ar[--index];
        return lowerSum;
    }

    //This can be fixed accordingly in a similar way lowerSum
    //was implemented to have a time complexity of O(n) but
    //this is not relevant to the problem here
    private int upperSum(int[] ar, int index)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i= index+1; i<ar.length; i++)
        {
            sum+=ar[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The above code does not produce the right results. For example for the following tests:

> ```
>   assertEquals(1, solution.solution(new int[]{1,2,1}));
>   assertEquals(3, solution.solution(new int[]{3,5,8,9,5,3,8}));
> ```

The first passes but the second does not. This is because the calculation of the 
lowerSum field is by +1 wrong. 
However making the following changes to the code produces the right result:

```
private int lowerSum =0;

 public int solution(int[] A) {
    for(int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
    {
        lowerSum(A, i);
        if( lowerSum== upperSum(A,i))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

 }    

private void lowerSum(int[] ar, int index)
{
    if(index == 0)
        lowerSum = 0;
    else
        lowerSum += ar[--index];

}
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Do everyone a favor. Whenever you post code, make sure that you don't have methods and variables with the same name :)

Comment: @LanguidSquid lol yeah I was confused as to how he was returning a function in java...

Comment: You're right! Sorry I didn't mean to complicate things more...

Comment: @BoDidely It is possible to return a function in java. And if the returned function was the same, it would be a recursive call.

Comment: @eagerToLearn In my mind I would consider that returning the return value of a function. When I said returning a function I meant like in Javascript where you can pass a function as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first implementation you simply return 0. In your second implementation you set `lowerSum` to 0 before returning `lowerSum`.

Fixed:

```
private int lowerSum(int[] ar, int index)
{
    if(index == 0) {
        lowerSum = 0;
    } else {
        lowerSum += ar[--index];
    }
    return lowerSum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the problem, but still I'm a bit confused. lowerSum is 0 since it was initialized. Why would it make a difference to explicitly assign 0 to it again?

Comment: If you make more than one call, the value of `lowerSum` could have changed from the last call.

Comment: You are calling the method in a loop that is altering a class level member. Given this, your results are changing because lowerSum was never reset to 0 when necessary. You assertion that the value was initially 0 is correct though.

Comment: Yes i totally understand. I should have either reset the value or create different objects for every test case. Thank you very much for you help :)